# Pass value to a template pages using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new in Angular since today. :)

I've followed a lot of tutorials since this morning and for each one the same question from my side without answer.

I saw that my navigation could be as simple as the following:

```
<h3>HTML</h3>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### JS

```
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});
```

But how it works if I need to page some value to a template page ?

And how can I get this passed value to use it in my template page ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Implement the controller and in it, declare the variables inside `$scope`, like `$scope.myVar`. Use it in the template as `myVar`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply 
define variable in controller `$scope.variablename=value;`
access in template as `variablename` inside double quotes or access as `{{variablename}}` outside the tag.

> Don't forget to inject `$scope` dependency in controller.

Answer (score -1):

Its all about using REST.
So lets say you want to pass a email id to your contact page, this is how your code would change.

```
//change in your html link. I have hard coded email for convenience. You could get it from $scope

 <li><a href="#contact/aaa@email.com">Contact</a></li>
```

Then you have to add the variables in your REST URL

```
//changes in your app.js
 // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html/:emailId',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
```

And finally changes in your controller.
You'll have to add dependency for "$stateParams" and then the variable value will be available in your controller

```
scotchApp.controller ('contactController',['$stateParams', function($stateParams){

var emailId = $stateParams.emailId;

]})
```